# C++ Inlinine function pointers and template function design

Tags: c++, embedded

Ok, I have a class which allows users to set pixels on a 100x64 LCD.

```
// (U8 = unsigned char)
inline void pixelOn(const U8 X, const U8 Y) {
   *(disp + ((Y / LCD_DEPTH) * LCD_WIDTH + X)) |= (1 << (Y % LCD_DEPTH));
}


inline void pixelOff(const U8 X, const U8 Y) {
   *(disp + ((Y / LCD_DEPTH) * LCD_WIDTH + X)) &= !(1 << (Y % LCD_DEPTH));
}
```

Now I have a class which draws a line on the lcd.
There are 3 functions which use different pixel "set funcitons" : show, erease, invert

```
void NLine::show(bool update) const {
    if(lcd == 0) return;

    if (!NLcd::pixelInLcd(x, y) && !NLcd::pixelInLcd(endX, endY))
        return;
    if ((x == endX) || (y == endY)) {
        straight(&NLcd::pixelOn);
    } else {
        bresenham(&NLcd::pixelOn);
    }
    visible = true;
    if (update) {
        display_update();
    }
}
```

At the moment a private function is called to set the pixels with a function pointer.

```
void NLine::bresenham(void (NLcd::*fpPixelState)(const U8, const U8)) const {
    // predetermine function to avoid ifs during calculation!
    // low level pixel functions use U8!
    S8 ix = x;
    S8 iy = y;
    S8 sx = ix < endX ? 1 : -1;
    S8 sy = iy < endY ? 1 : -1;
    S16 err = width + (-height), e2;

    for (;;) {
        // how to get the compiler to inline this (template?)!
        (lcd->*fpPixelState)(static_cast<U8>(ix), static_cast<U8>(iy));
        if (ix == endX && iy == endY)
            break;
        e2 = 2 * err;
        if (e2 > (-height)) {
            err += (-height);
            ix += sx;
        }
        if (e2 < width) {
            err += width;
            iy += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

I think its understandable that I want that the compiler inlines this function in the for loop. I tried to solve this problem with templates but there is the same problem that I do not know if the compiler use inline.
Should I use a complete different design or how could I solve this problem?
Next problem is that the compiler would generate a lot of code if I call show erase and invert because of different inlines, so I think I should use a different code design?

**EDIT:**

First, thx to Dietmar Kühl for design suggestion!
So here is the conclusion:

This is the test code:

```
NLine line(lcd, 0, 0, 99, 0);
t0 = timer.now();
for(S8 i=0; i<NLcd::LCD_HEIGHT; ++i) {
    // x0, y0, xend, yend
    line.setPosition(NLine::keep, i, NLine::keep, i);
    // call only straight not the bigger bresenham function
    line.show();
    line.erase();
    line.invert();
}
t1 = timer.now();
```

Method 1: Use funciton-pointers (first) 
memory: 26384 
RT: 51 ms

Method 2: Use function-objects (Dietmar Kühl) 
memory: 26592 
RT: 27 ms

Method 3: Use switch in for loop to determine the pixel operation function
memory: 26416
RT: 36 ms

Method 2: Best RT but it turns out that the program gets really big if the implementation
around the drawing methods get really big, especially for bresenham. This happens because the template implementation generates the full code for all 3 pixel functions.

Method 3: It seems that the simplest method is a good trade-off.

Further suggestions  are welcome.

Comment: You want to pass in a function pointer (determined at run-time) and that to be in-lined? In-lining is up to the compiler and would be done at compile time so that can't work - unless I've misundertsood.

Comment: No the function should not be determined at run-time. I call it always with a function which the compiler should know at compile-time. bresenham(&NLcd::pixelOn)

Comment: I think you misunterstood: I know that it does not work with function pointers, I search for a better solution.

Comment: If you want to give the compiler the best chance at inlining that thing make it a functor and pass an instance, and you can still invoke your function(s) from the functor. I am with Mats, however, in that I have doubts the function invoke is going to be critical compared to the math underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass a function as a pointer to another function, and expect the compiler to inline it, unless the code is REALLY trivial (such that the compiler can inline the function that the function pointer gets passed to). The compiler won't (typically) know that you are not going to pass some other function pointer in some other context (e.g. in a different compile unit), so, it will still have to "work" with the function pointer in place.

There are probably a few different ways that you could "fix" this, if it's REALLY that important - but the overhead of calling a function [through a pointer or not] is likely very small over the math you are doing (divide by LCD_DEPTH is expensive). Have you actually made measurements to identify that it's the call-time that makes the difference?

Also, your `pixelOff` code is probably wrong, I expect:

```
*(disp + ((Y / LCD_DEPTH) * LCD_WIDTH + X)) &= !(1 << (Y % LCD_DEPTH));
```

should be:

```
*(disp + ((Y / LCD_DEPTH) * LCD_WIDTH + X)) &= ~(1 << (Y % LCD_DEPTH));
```

since that would do the opposite of what the

Comment: I have actually made measurements: Drawing lines from left to right so that all pixels set to true. This means calling the pixel on function 100*64 times. With function pointer 17ms and with explicite inline 9 ms. On a microprocessor with RTOS time is really important. Yes it should be ~.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective approach is not to pass in a function pointer but rather to customize the function with a template argument specifying a function object. You can then pass in a function object with an inline function call operator (obviously, the member function needs to be declared correspondingly in the `NLine` clas:

```
template <typename PixelState>
    // PixelState is a function object taking
    // - a reference to an `NLcd`
    // - two U8 parameters and returns nothing
void NLine::bresenham(PixelState pixelState) const {
    // ...
    pixelState(lcd,static_cast<U8>(ix), static_cast<U8>(iy));
    // ...
}
```

The corresponding function objects can then be classes with a suitable function call operator, e.g.:

```
struct PixelOn
{
    void operator()(NLcd& lcd, U8 x, U8 y) const {
        lcd.pixelOn(x, y);
    }
};
// ...
bresenham(PixelOn());
// with C++ as of the 2011 revision:
bresenham([](Nlcd& lcd, U8 x, U8 y){ lcd.pixelOn(x, y); });
```

Function objects like these can generally be inlined by the compiler and the compilers tend to be good at inlining them as well since this technique is used frequently, e.g., with the standard C++ algorithms. Whether your particular function is actually inlined depends on whether the compiler decides to do so but it will generally make the most efficient choice (assuming a reasonable optimization level, of course). If `NLcd::pixelOn` can be inlined this function will also be inlined.